# Rave Raports "Generating page 1" problem

Tags: delphi

I have really annoying problem with RR. When I execute report from main window in my project it works fine but when I'll try execute report from modal window RR shows RvSystem setups, then I click OK [printer previev] and get message "Generatig page 1" - nothing happens next.

I have RR 7.5.2 with RAD Studio 2007.

**Update:**

When I call my window wit RR by `Show` not `ShowModal`, then execute report I have the same situation with message "Generating page 1", but when I minimize all windows (windows key + D) or use combination Alt+TAB - my report shows normally... It's weird for me.

Maybe my app is specific. Before I initialize all forms I have only one authentication window. When user properly log in I initialize all other forms. Next specific thing in my app is that I have ain menu on main form which is build dynamically from privilieges stored in database.

Maybe somethig from above specific things in my app interacts with RR... I've tried to change `RvSystem1.SysteOptions - soPrevievModal`. But after it, nothing fro RR shows.

It's really irritable. And seems that RR won't work with my app :(

Comment: If you have something to add to your question, just click on the edit link right underneath the tags. Don't post an answer.

Comment: User has presumably lost his original login, these are not the same "Look": http://stackoverflow.com/users/713765/look http://stackoverflow.com/users/714812/look

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude soShowStatus.

```
RvSystem1.SysteOptions - soPrevievModal - soShowStatus.
```